# Pinterest "Pin it" button is not working

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I'm trying to integrate pinterest into a website. I want to add "pin it" button. I couldn't make it work. Here is what I'm doing:

- Went to the following pinterest page:

  - http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/
- Under “Pin It” Button for Websites:

  - entered website address (http://www.polyvore.com/)
  - entered image url (http://embed.polyvoreimg.com/cgi/img-thing/size/y/tid/40748454.jpg)
  - Copied the code generated under "Basic":

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.polyvore.com%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Fembed.polyvoreimg.com%2Fcgi%2Fimg-thing%2Fsize%2Fy%2Ftid%2F40748454.jpg" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

- Pasted that before closing body tag.
- I can't see "Pin it" button as the document explains.

I might be doing something very stupid. Can anybody let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Works perfectly. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/hcV4F/ Can you describe where you are putting this in your website?

Comment: @enderskill: Thanks for the fiddle first of all! My basic problem is, however, when you are NOT LOGGED IN into Pinterest first BEFORE clicking the button you won’t be able to log in and then continue to share what you wanted to share. This is a problem one does not have with Facebook i.g. Here you simply log in and then the share dialog appears. How do you solve this?

Comment: @Garavani having the same issue here. If user not logged in sharing not happening on the first place. Found anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but It will give you only link on "Pin It" text. If you want the PinIt button then you need to write like you need to include img tag between anchor tag with given source - `src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It"`

```
<a
 href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.polyvore.com%2F&amp;media=http%3A%2F%2Fembed.polyvoreimg.com%2Fcgi%2Fimg-thing%2Fsize%2Fy%2Ftid%2F40748454.jpg"`enter code here`
 class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">  
   <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
                   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the olden days some images could not be pinned if they had certain characters in the filename/path. Your image/path seems fine but to get the button you need to choose button on their tool. The Pinterst Javascript is less sophisticated than Facebook, Twitter, or even Google+, you have to accept it's limitations. Pinterest on the whole is pretty simple, that is part of its' appeal.

Also images have to be a minimum size and not too big or they will also not be allowed to be pinned.

[Minimum Image Size has changed to 100 x 200 pixels](http://sociallysorted.com.au/pinterest-image-cheat-sheet-3-important-image-tips-you-need-to-know/)